# How many odd numbers between $0$ and $2018$ are there that the sum of its digits is an even number?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The title is pretty much all the problem, I can't seem to figure it out, got told I might have to use factorials (I don't see how?)

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? Have you tried anything?

Comment: "*Got told I might have to use factorials*"  No... factorials are not useful for this problem.  Rather, and more importantly, one could use the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) if you wanted (*which is the underlying principle which is where factorials come from*).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** If $0 \leq x \leq 999$ then exactly one of the numbers $x$ or $x+1000$ has odd sum of the digits.

This tells you immediately how many such numbers are between $0$ and $1999$. After that there are only few more left to check.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand though. The digit sums of the odd numbers (whether odd/even) is evenly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly: $$\{1,3,5,7,9,11,\cdots 2017\}\\ \Rightarrow\{\{1\},\{3\},\{5\},\{7\},\{9\},\{1,1\},\{1,3\},\{1,5\},\{1,7\},\{1,9\}\cdots\{2,0,1,7\}\}$$ 
$$S=\{1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10,\cdots 10\}$$ Taking $S\mod 2$ gives: $$\{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1\cdots1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0\}$$ The pattern is very clear, the $0$'s and $1$'s repeating every $5$ terms.

Since we have $\frac{2018}2$ odd numbers from $0$ to $2018$, we have $ (\frac{1009}2)=504.5\to504$ odd numbers with even digit sums.